# Icons for my iOS apps look blurry on device

Tags: iphone, ios, icons

I am new to iOS development and I am writing my first ios app but I have a problem about displaying icons.
Icons that I use on my app doesn't look like bright and nice like the icons in other apps or Apple default icons.

[image]

In the picture above, info icon looks like great (it's already ios info icon) but my star icon is terrible..
I have tried a lot of icons and all of these are the same...

edit: It looks like great on pc but not in my ipad or iphone..

This is how I use icons in my apps, icons are located in Supporting Files folder...

```
UIImage* image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Star.png"];
CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(0, 0, image3.size.width, image3.size.height);
UIButton *someButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg];
[someButton setBackgroundImage:image3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sendmail)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[someButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
```

Comment: Are you using retina image for those icons?

Comment: yes, I downloaded several retina icon set and tried.. no difference..

Comment: How do you load the image, what are the images name, what size are the images? You well need to to give use some more information.

Comment: @rckoenes I tried different icons and different sizes, 30x30,40x40 and 90x90...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To support high-resolution graphics on devices with retina displays, create two versions of the image: a standard size image, and a double-sized image with "@2x" added to the name:

Standard Size:
button.png
60 x 20 pixel
High Resolution:
button@2x.png
120 x 40 pixel

for details :
http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html

Comment: Thank you very much.. I've done everything in url and it looks like perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it on simple iPhone simulator and then on iPhone(Retina)simulator choosing the simulator from Hardware->device .If you image looks good on simple iPhone simulator and not on iPhone retina simulator then you should use image of double resolution then the one you currently have